# Abandoned Cart Functionality for Guest User

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

For a guest user, there needs to be a provision to capture the details of the cart which is abandoned.The flow should be as below:-

Any guest user/non-logged in user adds the product to the cart and tries to close the browser, then a pop up should appear which would have the details as below:-

Confused or still thinking about it?
Drop your contact details and we'll help you out!

1. Name
2. Phone number
3. Email id

Would be really grateful if someone can provide some kind of solution regarding how to implement this .

Answer (score 0):

We are using this module https://mirasvit.com/magento-extensions/follow-up-trigger-email-suite.html

They capture email and first/last name during checkout using JS and send these data to db (ajax). Even without order, we can send abandoned cart email.